# Correcting a transaction -- Gnucash won't let me do it

Tags: gnucash

I have been experimenting with splitting transactions so posted a question about it on this forum.  The answer I received did the trick and I can now split transactions just fine.  The trouble I'm facing is that I now have to correct the errors I created while experimenting.  For instance, the month of February has been reconciled and one of the messy split transactions was on 2/10.  My solution was to delete that transaction completely and re-enter it using the correct split method.  Gnucash won't let me do that.  Here's how it goes:

1. I start a new transaction and change the date to 2/10.  Press Tab.
2. Enter "Debit" in the Num field.  Press Tab.
3. Enter the Payee name in the Description field.  Press Tab.
4. Leave Account column blank since I'm going to split this transaction.  Press Tab.
5. In the Withdrawal column I enter the amount of the transaction.  Press Tab twice and enter "Split" in the Notes field.  Click the "Split" button in the header menu and then click on the Description field in the drop-down ledger lines.
6. Enter a description of the first split.  Press Tab.
7. Choose the target account for the first split.  Press Tab twice.......

And the entire new transaction simply disappears.  What gives?  I'm doing something really wrong.  Any ideas?

June 2, 2021

Yes, you are both right on.  The problem was rooted in my poor understanding of how Gnucash deals with accounts and how the split window works.  I think I have it figured out better now.  For instance, suppose I have a debit of $50.00 in my checking account that needs to be split between the Expenses:Groceries ($20) and Expenses:AutoParts ($30).  I would normally enter the full amount into my checking account as a debit and then press the 'Split' button on the top bar.  When the split lines appear below my transaction Gnucash automatically includes the original debit on one of the new lines.  That is what was confusing me.  I think I was deleting it, thinking it was not needed, and that's why my transaction disappeared from my checking account.  I know better now and have a better understanding of how the double-entry ledger model used by Gnucash works.  I now leave that line in place and enter the splits as credits into the respective accounts.  (In my example I would put $20 into Groceries and $30 into AutoParts.)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, this is a follow on question.  I applied the answer and it worked fine.  Now I have to clean up the mess I made while trying to solve the previous problem.  Hence this question.

Comment: It's difficult to exactly replicate your issue because some of the GnuCash behaviour depends upon the preferences that you have previously set.  HOWEVER, I think that the answer to your previous question is still valid; i.e. the visibility for a saved transaction is determined by the rules for showing existing transactions.  (1) The primary sort order for the current account register is based on the transaction date for each transaction.  If you saved a transaction for 10 Feb in an account register that included other transactions, the sort order may place your last transaction "off screen".

Comment: Or (2) if you saved the transaction with splits that only referred to accounts **OTHER THAN** the current account, then there's no reason that the saved transaction will appear in the current account view.  You will need to display the register for an account that involves a particular transaction for that transaction to be displayed.